# How can I distinct with condition?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Here is class `UserArrived`:

```
public class UserArrived{
   public string id{get;set;}
}
```

Here is class `OldUser`:

```
public class OldUser{
   public string id{get;set;}
   public DateTime lastArrived{get;set;}
}
```

And here is class `User`:

```
public class User{
   public string id{get;set;}
   public Boolean newUser{get;set;}
}
```

Finally, here is two `List`:

```
List<UserArrived> UserArrivedList=new List<UserArrived>();
List<OldUser> OldUserList=new List<OldUser>();
```

All the id in each class is unique.

Now I need to combine `UserArrived` and `OldUser` to a brand new `List<User>`.

As we know, the user arrives the shop may is a new user or an old user. If the user id in `UserArrived` also contains in `OldUser`, the property `newUser` in the new `List` is false for true.

In my opinion, I will combine two List into one first and then use the `distinct` method to remove the duplicates.

However, it seems the `distinct` can not run with a condition.

Although I can use several `foreach` to solve this while I feel it is so troublesome. I want to use something easy just like `lambda` or `linq`. How can I achieve this?

=============================

Here is an example of the input:

```
List<UserArrived> UserArrivedList=new List<UserArrived>(){new UserArrived(){id="A"},new UserArrived(){id="B"},new UserArrived(){id="C"}};
List<OldUser> OldUserList=new List<OldUser>(){new OldUser(){id="B",lastArrived=DateTime.Now}};
```

the output is:

```
A,true
B,false
C,true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need as final output

Comment: Can you keep sample data and what you expecte output to be in that lists.

Comment: @Muhammad I updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: @sriharsha I updated the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement you're saying that if an id is in both lists then the user is an old user, otherwise it is a new user.

So here's the simplest way that I could come up with to do it:

```
IEnumerable<User> users =
    Enumerable
        .Concat(
            UserArrivedList.Select(i => i.id),
            OldUserList.Select(i => i.id))
        .ToLookup(x => x)
        .Select(x => new User() { id = x.Key, newUser = x.Count() == 1 });
```

Let's test with some input:

```
var UserArrivedList = new List<UserArrived>()
{
    new UserArrived() { id = "A" },
    new UserArrived() { id = "B" },
};

var OldUserList = new List<OldUser>()
{
    new OldUser() { id = "B" },
    new OldUser() { id = "C" },
};
```

Here are my results:

[image: Users]

`B` is the only user who appears in both lists so should be `False`.

---

So, there's a bit of confusion about the requirements here.

The OP has added a concrete example of the input data and the expected output.

```
var UserArrivedList = new List<UserArrived>()
{
    new UserArrived() { id = "A" },
    new UserArrived() { id = "B" },
    new UserArrived() { id = "C" }
};

var OldUserList = new List<OldUser>()
{
    new OldUser() { id = "B", lastArrived = DateTime.Now }
};
```

With this input the OP is expecting `True, False, True` for `A, B, C` respectively.

Here is the code of the four current answers:

```
var results = new []
{
    new
    {
        answered = "Enigmativity",
        users = Enumerable
            .Concat(
                UserArrivedList.Select(i => i.id),
                OldUserList.Select(i => i.id))
            .ToLookup(x => x)
            .Select(x => new User() { id = x.Key, newUser = x.Count() == 1 })
    },
    new
    {
        answered = "JQSOFT",
        users = UserArrivedList.Select(x => x.id)
            .Concat(OldUserList.Select(y => y.id))
            .Distinct()
            .Select(x => new User
            {
                id = x,
                newUser = OldUserList.Count(o => o.id == x) == 0,
            })
    },
    new
    {
        answered = "Anu Viswan",
        users =
            UserArrivedList
                .Join(OldUserList, ual => ual.id, oul => oul.id, (ual, oul) => new User { id = oul.id, newUser = false })
                .Concat(UserArrivedList.Select(x => x.id).Except(OldUserList.Select(x => x.id))
                .Concat(OldUserList.Select(x => x.id).Except(UserArrivedList.Select(x => x.id)))
                .Select(x=> new User{ id = x, newUser = true}))
    },
    new
    {
        answered = "Barns",
        users =
            UserArrivedList.Select(i => i.id)
                .Union(OldUserList.Select(i => i.id))
                .Select(j => new User
                {
                    id = j,
                    newUser =
                        !(UserArrivedList.Select(i => i.id).Contains(j)
                            && OldUserList.Select(i => i.id).Contains(j))})
    }
};
```

That gives the output of:

[image: All Users]

So, currently all of the answers presented match the OP's example.

I'd be interested in the OP commenting on this as the input data:

```
    var UserArrivedList = new List<UserArrived>()
    {
        new UserArrived() { id = "A" },
        new UserArrived() { id = "B" },
    };

    var OldUserList = new List<OldUser>()
    {
        new OldUser() { id = "B" },
        new OldUser() { id = "C" },
    };
```

When I run this I get this output:

[image: Alternative Input]

Here three users match and one does not.

This all boils down to what the description means:

> As we know, the user arrives the shop may is a new user or an old user. If the user id in UserArrived also contains in OldUser, the property newUser in the new List is false for true.

Comment: Do you understand the question? :))

Comment: @JQSOFT - I feel I have - and I get the same results as Barns & Anu.

Comment: Now check the OP's edit and tell me who's wrong? The `newUser = OldUserList.Count(o => o.id == x) == 0,` was right after all. AND for sake of logic, how could an entry of a user who visits the shop for the first time be in both lists!!! Don't be hasty mate.  Good luck.

Comment: @JQSOFT - What's interesting now is that my code and your code produce the same result that the OP is looking for given his sample data.

Comment: @JQSOFT - This seems like a case of confirmation bias. The OP did not clarify their requirement. They simply gave a concrete example - **that matched both of our understandings of the requirement**. The OP really needs to clarify what they want.

Comment: @JQSOFT - I've updated my answer to show how each of the answers fair with the OP's suggested input and my suggested (and more complete) input.

Comment: No problem mate. Now let's move and find another one.

Comment: @JQSOFT - This is an excellent example of where the OP **thinks** he wrote a clear question and where he **thinks** he clarified the questions at hand, but in fact he did **neither**. What makes SO work so well is that users like us work hard to improve the quality of both the questions and the answers.

Comment: There are several ways while I prefer yours for it is the easiest. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Volfogg - No worries. Any chance you could clarify what the exact requirement was?

Comment: @Enigmativity it is for output a sheet about all the user info pre day. So I have to combine these two list into one.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about LINQ--it isn't always easy. In fact it can get quit cluttered. In the question statement I read,

> I want to use something easy just like lambda or linq.

Well, that is relative. But, I think that when using LINQ, one should try to keep it simple. Even break the statement down into multiple statements if necessary. For that reason I propose this solution (demonstrated in a console app):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------Test This Code -----------------------");

        var combined = TestUserCombined();

        //The following is just to demonstrate the list is populated properly
        combined.OrderBy(s => s.id.PadLeft(4, '0')).ToList().ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine($"X id: {k.id} | isNew:{k.newUser}"));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<User> TestUserCombined()
    {
        List<UserArrived> userArrivedList=new List<UserArrived>();
        List<OldUser> oldUserList=new List<OldUser>();

        //populate the lists...
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i+=2)
        {
            var userArrived = new UserArrived();
            userArrived.id = i.ToString();
            userArrivedList.Add(userArrived);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i+=3)
        {
            var oldUser = new OldUser();
            oldUser.id = i.ToString();
            oldUserList.Add(oldUser);
        }

        //Now for the solution...
        var selectedUserArrived = userArrivedList.Select(i => i.id);
        var selectedOldUser = oldUserList.Select(i => i.id);
        var users = selectedUserArrived
                             .Union(selectedOldUser)
                             .Select(j => new User{id=j,newUser=!(selectedUserArrived.Contains(j) && selectedOldUser.Contains(j))});
        return users;
    }
```

Certainly, this all could have been done in one statement, but I believe this makes it more readable and understandable.

---

**EDIT:** 
There has been some discussion amongst the coders posting solutions as to exactly what conditions must be met in order for the value "newUser" to be set to "true". It was my understanding from the initial posted question that the "id" must be present in both lists "UserArrivedList" AND "OldUserList", but I tend to agree with @JQSOFT that it makes more sense that the only condition that must be met should be that the "id" need only be present in "OldUserList". If that is indeed the case than the `Select()` expression above should be `.Select(j => new User{id=j,newUser=!selectedOldUser.Contains(j)});`

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks for the tip! I should have know that...or at least read the Docs better. That is one simplification and execution time saved!

Comment: Don't jump too soon. Your answer is correct for the OPs sample data and output. So far we don't have enough information to know who has the right interpretation here.

Comment: @JQSOFT - I try to avoid deleting comments. It just makes it confusing as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your query. One way to achieve this using Linq would be

```
    var users = UserArrivedList.Join(OldUserList,ual=>ual.id,oul=>oul.id,(ual,oul)=>new User{id=oul.id,newUser=false})
                               .Concat(UserArrivedList.Select(x=>x.id).Except(OldUserList.Select(x=>x.id))
                               .Concat(OldUserList.Select(x=>x.id).Except(UserArrivedList.Select(x=>x.id)))
                               .Select(x=> new User{id=x,newUser=true}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to create a distinct list of `User` type from two lists of different types; `UserArrived` and `OldUser` objects. A user is identified by a unique `id` of string type.

Accordingly, I'd suggest this:

```cs
var users = UserArrivedList.Select(x => x.id)
    .Concat(OldUserList.Select(y => y.id))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new User
    {
        id = x,
        newUser = OldUserList.Count(o => o.id == x) == 0,
    }).ToList();
```

Which gets the unique ids from both `UserArrivedList` and `OldUserList` and creates new `User` object for each. The `OldUserList.Count(o => o.id == x) == 0,` assigns `false` to the `newUser` property if the user `id` exists in the `OldUserList` otherwise `true`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Who told you that? Did you try it?

Comment: You get different results to Barns, Anu, & I.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, I like Barms's already. Now leave the right results for the OP, he knows what he needs not you. Good day.

Comment: Your code `OldUserList.Count(o => o.id == x) == 0` is saying if the `id` is not in the old list then the user must be new. The OP says "If the user id in UserArrived also contains in OldUser, the property newUser in the new List is false for true." which is different.

Comment: I had a look at some of your other answers. You are a good solid coder and your write good answers. I think in this case you have just misunderstood the OP's requirements - they were a bit convoluted IMO.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, you could help a member to understand without downvoting as well :) Just like what I did with Barms..

Comment: I agree that the question statement was difficult to understand--the requirements for the final result was unclear regarding the desired value for "newUser" (at least until the OP edited the question statement). As a matter of fact, I considered annotating my solution with the caveat that I was guessing at the desired result. JQSOFT obviously has an excellent understanding of the code--I like his base solution. @Enigmativity solution is very elegant and succinct. I wish you both well and I am looking forward to seeing more solutions from you both on SO.

Comment: @Barns No hard feelings buddy, It's just a Hard Talk. Frankly, I learn a lot from his posts and I'm learning from yours now. Thank you both.